# Existence condition of Real Eigenvalues for Non-Symmetric Real Matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have to solve this eigenproblem:

$$Ax=\lambda Bx$$

Where $A$ and $B$ are generic submatrices (not principal) obtained  from symmetric and real matrices $A_s$ and $B_s$ so it is obvious that in general $A$ and $B$ are non symmetric but real matrix. With $\lambda$ eigenvalue and $x$ the corresponding eigenvector.
I know that for principal submatrices hold the Interlacing theorem since $A_s$ and $B_s$ are symmetric and real.

But, which conditions hold about the existence of real eigenvalues for the other submatrices?

Comment: Sorry but I don’t understand the set up for that problem, A and B are scalar multiple?

Comment: Problem should be clear now